# Netbeans background scanning project stuck

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using **netbeans 7.4** for a Java EE project for school.  
Now recently when I open netbeans, the background scanning of the project takes ages.  
If i check the IDE log, I see that i get alot of INFO about netbeans not beeing able to read symbolic links to files in my Library.  
These links are to files in the Frameworks folder.  
Before, netbeans scanned a folder named Tex in de Library, but I deleted that, since I didn't need it anymore, but deleting the Frameworks folder I don't trust that much.
  
Since netbeans keeps scanning, I can't run my project.  
  
Can someone help me?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21721822/875083

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stop NetBeans scanning projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515622/is-there-a-way-to-stop-netbeans-scanning-projects)