# Prevent NetBeans 8.1 from Scanning the Project

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am well aware this issue exists but I wasn't able to find a fix (that works) yet. 
There's a quite big project I have to import/open in NetBeans 8.1 and this process just takes an eternity and causes several problems every time.

I started it in the command-line on Linux so here's the output:

```
qohelet@PC ~/netbeans-8.1/bin $ ./netbeans 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to /home/users/qohelet/.netbeans/8.1/var/log/heapdump.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [1552345961 bytes in 15.428 secs]
```

You can see the problem right here, while the project scans I get several "**Lack of Memory**" messages which give forward me to the following Notification:

> Resolve Parsing Problem
>
> The IDE has detected slowness in parsing the project, which is caused
>   by a lack of available memory. For solutions to this problem, search
>   the IDE help for "Memory Requirements for Large Projects"

**What do I actually want and why do I have 8.1?**

I'm working on a C++ project that contains several Python and Perl Scripts. NB 8.1 is the last version that has (quite good) plugins for Python and Perl.

Just canceling the process doesn't work.

There are "solutions" to that, I know, so far none of them worked for me:

- [Netbeans scanning of project too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076705/netbeans-scanning-of-project-too-slow)

  - Basically the same with me, just unchecking that box did nothing
- [Is there a way to stop NetBeans scanning projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515622/is-there-a-way-to-stop-netbeans-scanning-projects)

  - Not helpful, I just have one project and it's not Java
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSlowNetBeans

  - Seems NetBeans is well aware of that problem but the article is pretty old and probably doesn't refer to 8.1

There are some switches for the `netbeans.conf` apparently to give more memory to the IDE, but it seems most of them are non existent any more. (Xmx)

Comment: Re using Xmx, here is a NetBeans 8.1 bug report response which urges the user to use Xmx to prevent OutOfMemoryError: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257737 So what happens when you specify Xmx?

Comment: Using `./netbeans -J-Xmx1500m` now, the issue is gone now. Seems I did use the parameter wrong

Comment: @skomisa - I built the project externally. Netbeans really has issues with that. Parsing the trunk like hell

Answer (score 1):

**Just give it more memory.**

Find "netbeans_default_options" in your *netbeans.conf* file add -J-Xmx option:

> netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss4m -J-Xms64m ***-J-Xmx5G***
>   -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

My NetBeans works pretty good with 5GB of RAM when I open whole linux kernel as a project.